# How to create correct legend entries in seaborn for line plots of different styles and a scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a question how to combine three plots with different linestyle and adjust the legend accordingly. I have two line charts consisting each of two lines. One is solid lined the other dashed. On top I'm adding a scatter plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple
import numpy as np
#sample data generation
plot_df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(5), columns=["Series 1", "Series 2"], data=np.array([[1, 2],[2.4, 5],[4.1, 7.1],[5, 8.9],[5.2, 10]]))
plot_df_dash = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(5), columns=["Series 1 dashed", "Series 2 dashed "], data=np.array([[2, 3],[3.4, 4],[5.1, 6.1],[7, 1.9],[4.2, 12]]))
plot_df_points = pd.DataFrame(index = [1.5, 2, 3.7], columns = ["Series 1", "Series 2"], data=np.array([[1.2, 3.4],[4.5, 6.9],[5.5, 9.6]]))
df = pd.DataFrame(plot_df.stack()).reset_index()
df_dash = pd.DataFrame(plot_df.stack()).reset_index()
df.columns = ["x", "Series","y"]
df_dash.columns=["x", "Series dashed","y"]
df_points = pd.DataFrame(plot_df_points.stack()).reset_index()
df_points.columns = ["x", "Series","y"]

#plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.lineplot(data=df,x="x",y="y", hue="Series",ax=ax,palette="rocket",linewidth=2.5)
sns.lineplot(data=df_dash,x="x",y="y", hue="Series dashed",ax=ax,palette="rocket",linewidth=2.5,linestyle="--")
sns.scatterplot(data=df_points, x="x", y="y", hue="Series", ax=ax,s=200)

#generating legend
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend([tuple(handles[::2]), tuple(handles[1::2])], labels[:4], handlelength=3,
          handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=None)})

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

I'm struggling to get the right legend. The scatter plot should be used across the dashed and solid line plot. That means the legend should show 4 entries, two solid lines with circles from the scatter plot plus two dashed lines with circles from the same scatter plot.

Comment: It does display the dashed line. But the values are the same, so you don't see these lines. Add `df_dash.y *= 2` to prove this. And what is `HandlerTuple()`?

Comment: @Mr.T thanks for the y values! I've added hte line ofr `HandlerTuple()`. Forgot to copy that one, thanks. It is `from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple`

Comment: Seaborn creates another problem when generating your legend entries. Not sure why linestyle and linewidth are ignored. Probably because color and linestyle parameters are usually controlled by hue and style keywords overruling your settings. You probably have to change the linestyle in the legend manually. Maybe a pure matplotlib plot is less hassle.

Comment: I would probably just directly specify the legend handles rather than extracting and modifying them: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#proxy-legend-handles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said, one way is to manually set the correct line properties in the legend handles.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple
import numpy as np
#sample data generation
plot_df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(5), columns=["Series 1", "Series 2"], data=np.array([[1, 2],[2.4, 5],[4.1, 7.1],[5, 8.9],[5.2, 10]]))
plot_df_dash = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(5), columns=["Series 1 dashed", "Series 2 dashed "], data=np.array([[2, 3],[3.4, 4],[5.1, 6.1],[7, 1.9],[4.2, 12]]))
plot_df_points = pd.DataFrame(index = [1.5, 2, 3.7], columns = ["Series 1", "Series 2"], data=np.array([[1.2, 3.4],[4.5, 6.9],[5.5, 9.6]]))
df = pd.DataFrame(plot_df.stack()).reset_index()
#changed the dataframe generation here - the reason why you did not see dashed lines
df_dash = pd.DataFrame(plot_df_dash.stack()).reset_index()
df.columns = ["x", "Series","y"]
df_dash.columns=["x", "Series dashed","y"]
df_points = pd.DataFrame(plot_df_points.stack()).reset_index()
df_points.columns = ["x", "Series","y"]

#plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#same color palette for the series
sns.color_palette("rocket")
#defining linestyle and width for dashed line
ls = "--"
lw = 3.5
sns.lineplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", hue="Series", ax=ax, linewidth=2.5)
sns.lineplot(data=df_dash, x="x", y="y", hue="Series dashed", ax=ax, linewidth=lw, linestyle=ls)
sns.scatterplot(data=df_points, x="x", y="y", hue="Series", ax=ax, s=200)

#generating legend
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
#manipulating appearance of wrongly generated seaborn line2D objects for dashed lines
for i in [2, 3]:
    handles[i].set_linestyle(ls) 
    handles[i].set_linewidth(lw) 
#generate legend entries as suggested by you
ax.legend([tuple([handles[0], handles[4]]), 
           tuple([handles[1], handles[5]]), 
           tuple([handles[2], handles[4]]), 
           tuple([handles[3], handles[5]])], 
           labels[:4], handlelength=7, 
           handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=None)})

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

As an aside, it turned out you didn't see the dashed lines because you wrongly attributed df values to df_dash.

If you only wanted to generate series entries as line properties are often explained in figure legends, the code would simplify to:

```
#generating legend
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
for i in [2, 3]:
    handles[i].set_linestyle(ls) 
    handles[i].set_linewidth(lw)         

ax.legend([tuple(handles[::2]), tuple(handles[1::2])], labels[:2], handlelength=10,
          handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=None)})

plt.show()
```

[image]